# How can I get parts of a string separated by columns

Tags: python, string

What I need to separate is a string that has been divided by columns.

For example the string:

```py
my_string = "username:id:token"
```

How would I go about trying to get the username, id and token into separate variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this

```
username, ID, token = my_string.split(':')
```